# How do I ensure a docker network (interface) exists even when it's not running?

Tags: docker, postgresql, systemd

I have a container stack (specified by a `docker-compose.yml`). The stack requires a PostgreSQL database, but I am using a locally running native instance instead of having it be a part of the stack (to make e.g. backups easier, and to conserve resources). The PostgreSQL instance is set to bind and listen on `172.17.0.1`, the IP under which the host is reachable from within docker containers.

However, during system startup, PostgreSQL doesn't bind to that address, and the containers subsequently fail to initialize. If I restart PostgreSQL afterwards, I can see it's bound (via `ss`), and the containers initialize fine. This is 100% reproducible on every boot.

I think it's because the interface doesn't exist yet, so there's nothing to bind to. Is there a way to "persist" the network (or the interface) so that it can be bound to even while docker hasn't initialized yet?

(I've also tried specifying `After=docker.service` in the systemd service file for PostgreSQL, with no luck - I think it's because while docker has already initialized, the container stacks haven't, and so the networks haven't been yet created either. Specifying "wait until a docker container has started" in systemd is impossible as far as I'm aware.)

Comment: I worked around a similar issue by using OVS instead of Docker's networking.  There's a slight learning curve but it has more capabilities than the standard Docker networking.  This may or may not be useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

I have been dealing with the same problem. I found a solution, but you might not like it. If you set `listen_addresses` in your Postgresql to `'*'`, then it will bind to the `0.0.0.0` address instead, which will receive traffic from all interfaces. I've confirmed that this works right on several servers.

Yes, it's a sin to let your DB server bind to your public-facing address. You should already have UFW blocking external traffic though, plus a strictly configured `pg_hba` only allowing connections to the appropriate DBs from the Docker subnet, plus only local unix auth for the `postgres` superuser account and strong passwords for all other accounts, so I suppose it's safe enough. It works, at least, and I haven't been able to find any other way to make it work.

Comment: Thanks! I'll leave the question open, as this is more of a work-around than an actual solution. FWIW, in the meantime I ended up doing sort of the "opposite" of what you describe - I set it so that the container is `network_mode: host`, meaning it can just connect to postgres via `localhost`. This also works, but is also non-ideal in its own way.